# Make hyperlink clickable when accessibility is on

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm making application accessible using accessibility with Talk/Voice Over.

> How to make links clickable with accessibility?

Using following methods for making `Hyperlink` clickable in `TextView`.

```
/**
 * This method creates the link and associates the ClickableSpan to it.
 * Once the ClickableSpan is clicked, it will call the 
 * ClickableSpanListener.performAction
 */
public static void makeLinkClickable(
  final ClickableSpanListener clickableSpanListener,
  final SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder,
  final URLSpan span) {
final int start = strBuilder.getSpanStart(span);
final int end = strBuilder.getSpanEnd(span);
final int flags = strBuilder.getSpanFlags(span);

//get the String that is used as the link
final char[] characters = new char[end - start];
strBuilder.getChars(start, end, characters, 0);

  final ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
    public void onClick(final View view) {
       clickableSpanListener.performAction(span.getURL(), new String(characters));
     }
   };
  strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, start, end, flags);
  strBuilder.removeSpan(span);
}

/**
 * This method takes in a String that contains at least one link defined by HTML <a></a> tags.
 * A link will be created in the String and added to the TextView.
 * The link will become clickable and the action (onClick) is defined by the
 * ClickableSpanListener.
 */
  public static void setTextViewHTML(
  final ClickableSpanListener clickableSpanListener,
  final TextView text,
  final String html) {
final CharSequence sequence = Html.fromHtml(html);
final SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(sequence);
final URLSpan[] urls = strBuilder.getSpans(0, sequence.length(), URLSpan.class);
  for (final URLSpan span : urls) {
    makeLinkClickable(clickableSpanListener, strBuilder, span);
    }
   text.setText(strBuilder);
   text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
 }

/**
 * This is the interface that should be implemented by classes to define the action
 * that will occur when a clickablespan is clicked
 */
 public interface ClickableSpanListener {
    void performAction(String url, String linkText);
 }


 setTextViewHTML(
    this,
    txtTermsPrivacy,
    getString(R.string.terms_condition_privacy_policy)
);
```

Tried:

As mentioned in the google support for accessibility [Google Support - Accessibility](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6378148?hl=en), I have tried using [Linkify](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify) but it does not seem to work though.

Comment: How you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6378148?hl=en), the user will need to access the `Local Context Menu` via a `TalkBack` gesture (default gesture is `Swipe up then right`) to activate a `TextView` link.

In fact, any clickable `span` on a `TextView` widget may be activated through `TalkBack` using its context menu, even links that don't open a browser. Your implementation of `performAction` may show a `Toast` message, and the user will be able to activate through the context menu.

I tested it with `TalkBack 7.3.0` in `Android 8.1` with `Linkify` and `android:autoLink="web"`. Both are working as expected.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="This is a TextView with link to StackOverflow: http://www.stackoverflow.com, and to Android Documentation: https://developer.android.com." />
```

[image: TalkBack context menu listing TextView links to activate]

Answer (score 0):

```
val clickSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                // Handel your click
                Util.launchUrl(activity, getString(R.string.permissions_request_agreement_url))
            }
        }

        val agreementLabel = getString(R.string.permissions_request_agreement_label)
        val textHeadingSpannable: SpannableString = SpannableString(agreementLabel)

        //From "I agree to the Optus Privacy Policy", make "Optus Privacy Policy" clickable
        textHeadingSpannable.setSpan(clickSpan, 15, agreementLabel.length, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        privacyLink.text = textHeadingSpannable

        privacyLink.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()

        listener = ValidatedListener {
            btnPrimary.isEnabled = isValidated()
        }
```

On the other hand:

```
<string name="permissions_request_agreement_label">I agree to the Optus Privacy Policy</string>

<string name="permissions_request_agreement_url">https://www.optus.com.au/about/legal/privacy/telco-services</string>
```

[Reference and also Java sample](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/clickablespan)